# tnamserv: can we get more logs?

Tags: java, corba, nameservice

Can we get more verbose when using the "tnameserv" utility delivered with the standard JDK?

When running it, we only get:

```
[test@localhost someDir]$ tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 2600
Initial Naming Context:
IOR:000000000000002b49444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e300000000000010000000000000096000102000000000a3132372e302e302e31000a2800000045afabcb0000000020000f424000000001000000000000000200000008526f6f74504f41000000000d544e616d65536572766963650000000000000008000000010000000114000000000000020000000100000020000000000001000100000002050100010001002000010109000000010001010000000026000000020002
TransientNameServer: setting port for initial object references to: 2600
Ready.
```

When binding objects to it (or clients connect to it, or errors occurs, ...), nothing more is logged!

Comment: Did you tried tnameserv -J-verbose

Comment: No, but I tried it just now. It's basically only logging things like this: <br />[Loaded org.omg.CosNaming.Binding from /usr/bin/jdk1.6.0_23/jre/lib/rt.jar]

Comment: Have you tried the CORBA debug property?: "tnameserv.exe -J-Dcom.sun.CORBA.ORBDebug=transport,giop,poa,subcontract", I think that's all the sublogging levels